# SmackInitialization: Could not determine Smack version

Tags: android, xmpp, unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

I am making an android plugin for Unity, I need to integrate XMPP in Unity so first I am trying to create a connection of XMPP and send and receive a message. **It's working fine in android, I am able to send and receive message** But when I export **.jar** file and use in Unity so I got below error while I create connection

```
SmackInitialization: Could not determine Smack version
  java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
  at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
  at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:122)
  at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:57)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.<clinit>(SmackInitialization.java:61)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.getVersion(SmackConfiguration.java:96)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.<clinit>(ConnectionConfiguration.java:38)
  at com.arvaan.myplugins.ToastExample.connectXMPP(ToastExample.java:99)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't know what is an issue with Smack, I am new in Unity, I know how to create plugins and call method in Unity but don't know what's wrong over here.

Please check code :

```
public class ToastExample extends UnityPlayerActivity implements ConnectionListener, ChatManagerListener, RosterListener, PingFailedListener, StanzaListener, MessageListener, ChatMessageListener {

private static final String TAG = ToastExample.class.getSimpleName();
private AbstractXMPPConnection mConnection = null;
private ChatManager chatManager;
private Chat chat;
private Context context;
private String userName = "";
private String passWord = "";
private String objectName = "";
private static ToastExample instance;

public ToastExample() {
    this.instance = this;
}
public static ToastExample instance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ToastExample();
    }
    return instance;
}
public void setContext(Context context) { // This is also working fine
    Log.e(TAG, "setContext called");
    this.context = context;
}
public void showMessage(String message) { // I can able to see toast
    Toast.makeText(this.context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void connectXMPP(String host, int port, String userName, String passWord) {
    Log.e(TAG, "_connectXMPP called");
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder(); // Here i got error
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(userName, passWord);
    ...............
    ...............
}
```

I am using below **.Jar** file in My Plugin and Unity

```
smack-core-4.1.4.jar
smack-extensions-4.1.4.jar
smack-im-4.1.4.jar
smack-android-4.1.4.jar
smack-android-extensions-4.1.4.jar
smack-tcp-4.1.4.jar
jxmpp-util-cache-0.4.2.jar
jxmpp-core-0.4.2.jar
jxmpp-jid-0.4.2.jar
jxmpp-stringprep-libidn-0.4.2.jar
minidns-core-0.2.0.jar**
```

Someone is also facing this issue but not found [Check more](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/59325)

Please help me to sort out this issue, Thanks in Advance.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has answered here I how I solved it after 4 days R&D:

1. Please exrect all classes of Smack-core-4.1.1.jar file and past inside your app.
2. There is other 3 more file : version, smack-config.xml,jul.properties , Please paste this file in your Assests folder inside app.
3. In Smack packages there is one class : SmackInitialization.java, please replace below code. [Code Here](http://prntscr.com/e2jjdd)
4. Once you done please make .Jar file and use inside your Unity.[Check Here](http://prntscr.com/e2jju1)

Let me know if you got same error i am happy to help you anytime for any solution.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I keep getting errors (with dns resolver). Can you please email me base project that you got working (with chat libs only)? I would really appreciate this. Thank you.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mmvlad/35f51f8c438651608350273437c1fc65
I added smack-resolver-minidns, minidns-core to libs but error still exists

Comment: @VladyslavMelnychenko you can always post your own question if you want to get help. Link to this answer if you think it's related.

Comment: You create an `inputstream` to read the hard coded strings bytes just to create a buffered reader to read the hardcoded line in the first place to set `smackVersion`. Nice! You could just delete the entire method and hardcode `smackVersion = "4.1.4 (4.1.4 2015-09-14)"`